# How do we write CSS like Wordpress with expanding right div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

We are writing a custom website, but we want it to look similar to Wordpress, so we have written the code with the 'sticky' left position bar, and the scrolling right one.

But when you bring the page inward, the right columns wraps under the left one.  Any ideas why and how to resolve?

Here is the CSS code:

```
html, body, section, article, aside {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.sidemenu
{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
background-color: #333333;
color: #ffffff;
width: 160px;
float: left;
}

.menu-link a
{
padding: 8px 2px 2px 8px;
display: block;
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: capitalize;
}

.pagebody
{
float: left;
max-width: 95%;
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
}
```

So you have two DIVs, left is 'sidemenu' right is 'pagebody'.

Hope you can help.

Comment: could you please provide some demo?

Comment: Look into using media queries to change the style of the site based on the size of the viewport.

Comment: Unable to provide demo as it is nowhere near live.  But if you are aware of how WP Admin page looks, you will know what I mean.  You have the black menu down the left, and the page on the right.    So in code it is like this:  

```<div class="sidemenu">
<?php
include "menu.php";
?>
</div>
<div class="pagebody">
<?php
getPage($pdo);
?>
</div>
<div style='clear: both'></div>```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the position of the sidebar, you need to used `position: fixed;`. After that, wrap the sidebar div and body div into one container and set its width to 100% (I also gave the body a margin of 0 at this point to remove gaps).

Give the body div a left-margin equal to the width of the sidebar, then set the width of the body using a calculation (as shown below). I also gave it a really long height to demonstrate scrolling.

You can omit your floats.

Here is the adjusted code:

```css
html,
body,
section,
article,
aside {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidemenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 160px;
}

.menu-link a {
  padding: 8px 2px 2px 8px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.pagebody {
  width: calc(100% - 199.75px);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 300vh;  /**** used to demonstrate scrolling ****/
  margin-left: 160px;
  background-color: #BBB;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidemenu">
    Side Menu

  </div>

  <div class="pagebody">
    body

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that is very nice.  How does this bit work:
width: calc(100% - 199.75px);

The issue with 'fixed' is that if the left menu is taller than the screen, you cannot scroll it down to view more elements (like Wordpress).  That's why it was 'sticky', not fixed.  Is there a tweak to make it happen?

Comment: @simon_a6 - `width: calc(100% - 199.75px);` works by setting the width of the body container to the entire width of the page, then subtracting just enough to prevent overflow.

To make the sidebar scrollable, simply add `overflow-y:scroll;` to the .sidemenu class in your css.

Comment: Mmmmm that's not quite right tho.  It makes it messy.  The left pane is there a self scroller (like an iframe).  The way I had it before, when you scroll down the page, after you get the to bottom it also moves the left one.  Wordpress does it perfect, hence trying to duplicate that style.

Comment: The way WP does it, when you scroll down, the entire page scroll down... But when the left menu reaches the end, it stops, but the right one keeps going to the bottom.  There is only the one browser scroller on the right.  

That's what I am trying to get to with this.  Your method is a kind of plan B I suppose, and looks like an iframe, but I prefer it to be as described if I Can.